# Converting the javascript object to json object

Tags: javascript, json, loggly

I am creating a object of logMessage.

```
logMessage = function (msg, severity, vendorId, userName, actionPerformed, priority, traceId, dataSent) {
    this.message = msg;
    this.severity = severity;
    this.vendorId = vendorId;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.actionPerformed = actionPerformed;
    this.priority = priority;
    this.traceId = traceId;
    this.dataSent = dataSent;
};

var msg = new logMessage(err, "High", "none", qry.username, "Error on login call: /req/login", "high", "", qry);
Utility.writeToLoggly(msg);
```

`err ,qry` are json objects; How do I convert the the msg object to json object ?
I am sending the `msg` object to `loggly` for the log management. It would be great if I could send the correctly formated json object to `loggly` .

Comment: `JSON.stringify(msg)`

Comment: NB: by convention JS "classes" start with an upper case letter.

Comment: p.s. Googling for "javascript json output" trivially produces several pages with the correct answer.

Comment: BTW: there is no such thing as a JSON *object*. JSON is a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
logMessage = function (msg, severity, vendorId, userName, actionPerformed, priority, traceId, dataSent) {
    this.message = msg;
    this.severity = severity;
    this.vendorId = vendorId;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.actionPerformed = actionPerformed;
    this.priority = priority;
    this.traceId = traceId;
    this.dataSent = dataSent;
};

var msg = new logMessage(err, "High", "none", qry.username, "Error on login call: /req/login", "high", "", qry);
Utility.writeToLoggly(JSON.stringify(msg));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the JSON.stringify() function, so just add to your code:

```
Utility.writeToLoggly(JSON.stringify(msg));
```